# Different DocumentRoots in Apache based on HTTP Auth

Tags: apache, http, authentication

Does Apache (or another web server) have configuration support that would allow a user (me!) to set a different webroot based on the value of an authenticated HTTP user?

i.e.

Apache supports [setting a particular folder on a server as a web site's document root](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Apache supports [using HTTP Auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) to allow users access to resources.

The end goal I want is, if user A accesses `http://example.com`, they're served files from one folder.  If user B accesses `http://example.com` (the same URL), they're served files from a different folder.

(this is borderline webmaster material -- but the it's part of a larger programatic project, will likely involve conditional/programatic logic, so I'm erring on the side of asking on Stack Overflow)

Comment: I think no, at least not directly, because authentication is always directory-based so the current working directory is already decided on at the point when you can check for user auth. Not sure whether anything can be done with a clever RewriteCond that uses the authenticated user as a variable, checking....

Comment: OK, it might be possible with `mod_rewrite`. Here is a relevant-looking writeup (Google Cache only because the site in question seems to be down):  https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:n5LI_BF6CUwJ:https://digitalelf.net/2010/01/apache-mod-rewrite-based-on-logged-in-user/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us